# How to set interval after clearing it

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I can set interval and clear it on click. I want to setInterval again but don't know how to do. What I want is when someone clicks on an icon then setInterval should be clear (best if it waits for few seconds) and then start again. Here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    var timer =  setInterval(function(){
    var finding = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap').find( "li.active" );
    var tabcontentActive = jQuery('div.tab-content').find( "div.active" );
    var last = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li').last();
    var nextItem =  jQuery(finding).next();
    var tabid = jQuery(nextItem).find('a').attr('id');
    if(finding.is(last)) {
     var tabid = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li:first').find('a').attr('id');   
    }
    //alert(tabid);
     jQuery(finding).removeClass('active');
     jQuery(finding).next().addClass('active');
     if(finding.is(last)) {
        jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li:first').addClass('active');
    }
    jQuery(tabcontentActive).removeClass('active');
    jQuery('div.tab-content').find('div#'+tabid).addClass('active');
    }, 3000);
     $("ul.hi-icon-wrap li").click(function () {
          //alert('ok');
          clearInterval(timer); //clear interval
        timer = setInterval(timer, 300); //I am unable to restart here. 
      });

});
```

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval`/`setTimeout` returns just number indicating process reference, not actual function called. Call same function again.

```
var fooFunction = function(){
    var finding = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap').find( "li.active" );
    var tabcontentActive = jQuery('div.tab-content').find( "div.active" );
    ...
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var timer =  setInterval(fooFunction, 3000);

     $("ul.hi-icon-wrap li").click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer); //clear interval
        timer = setInterval(fooFunction, 300); //I am unable to restart here. 
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it put this piece of code in your function as you see below. You are calling [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) which clears things out ,if you want to restart it again you must set new interval.

> The `clearInterval()` method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin
>   cancels a timed, repeating action which was previously established by
>   a call to setInterval().

```
function interval(){
    var finding = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap').find( "li.active" );
    var tabcontentActive = jQuery('div.tab-content').find( "div.active" );
    var last = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li').last();
    var nextItem =  jQuery(finding).next();
    var tabid = jQuery(nextItem).find('a').attr('id');
    if(finding.is(last)) {
    var tabid = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li:first').find('a').attr('id');   
}
    jQuery(finding).removeClass('active');
    jQuery(finding).next().addClass('active');
    if(finding.is(last)) {
        jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li:first').addClass('active');
    }
    jQuery(tabcontentActive).removeClass('active');
    jQuery('div.tab-content').find('div#'+tabid).addClass('active');
}
```

and then

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var timer = setInterval(interval,3000);
    // do nothing 
    $("ul.hi-icon-wrap li").click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer); //clear interval
        timer = setInterval(interval, 300);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `setInterval` logic in different function and call that function when button is clicked.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    var timer;
    startInterval();
    
    function startInterval(){
    timer =  setInterval(function(){
    var finding = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap').find( "li.active" );
    var tabcontentActive = jQuery('div.tab-content').find( "div.active" );
    var last = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li').last();
    var nextItem =  jQuery(finding).next();
    var tabid = jQuery(nextItem).find('a').attr('id');
    if(finding.is(last)) {
     var tabid = jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li:first').find('a').attr('id');   
    }
    //alert(tabid);
     jQuery(finding).removeClass('active');
     jQuery(finding).next().addClass('active');
     if(finding.is(last)) {
        jQuery('ul.hi-icon-wrap li:first').addClass('active');
    }
    jQuery(tabcontentActive).removeClass('active');
    jQuery('div.tab-content').find('div#'+tabid).addClass('active');
    }, 3000);
  }
  
  $("ul.hi-icon-wrap li").click(function () {
          //alert('ok');
          clearInterval(timer); //clear interval
        startInterval(); //I am unable to restart here. 
    });
      
});
```